# Logical volume not found. Kubuntu only boots into an emergency/root mode

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu

I get these errors during the boot sequence:

> Volume group "kubuntu-vg" not found
>   Cannot process volume group kubuntu-vg

And later:

> Failed to connect lvmetad

There might be other error messages; they all whip by pretty fast, and I don't know if the lines I'm quoting are the relevant ones.

At the end, it says, "Welcome to emergency mode!", and takes me to a root shell. I can start the desktop from here in root mode, but that's obviously not optimal, and for some reason the Networking service doesn't run, which presents a barrier to reinstalling things with apt

This problem started after I was using Testdisk to recover deleted files.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

It seems that one of my partitions is not mounting during boot; could this be causing it? Do I need to edit /etc/fstab?

Why isn't the kubuntu-vg volume group being found? It seems this is this the root of the problem. What tells the system where to look for logical volumes?

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo fdisk -l`. Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu partition? What were you trying to recover using testdisk?

Comment: Here are the outputs: https://m.imgur.com/a/e1Sh5

Comment: **Your problem is with your /etc/fstab**. Have you been manually editing it? It looks like there's more than one error, but because I'm not that familiar with LVM and encryption, I can't give you the exact fix. Hopefully you'll catch someone more familiar with those.

Comment: I think your diagnosis is probably right @heynnema

Comment: Yes, multiple errors I think. The sda1 line mount on /dev/ is wrong, as is the 2 at the end of that same line. Plus mounts for /boot and /boot/efi. And the missing "0 0" at then end of the last two lines. Quite a mess.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the system to generate a new /etc/fstab, the way it would during installation?

Comment: Trying to rebuild fstab now. The hard bit is figuring out approximate mount points for each. Any tips how to go about that? What are good mountpoints for sda1, 2 and 3?

Comment: If I was more familiar with LVM and encryption, I'd just write a new fstab for you. But yours is in such a state... I can see some of the errors, but not enough to be able to fix each one. I'd say that somebody else has to help you further with a possible rewrite, or you'd have to reinstall to generate a new fstab. The data that I requested first, should help somebody do that... it's all the data they need. Sorry.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab for some help.